# Sitecore, custom MVC controllers and routes

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-mvc-5, sitecore, sitecore7

I have a website defined in Sitecore's site definitions. The path to it is `/localhost/mysite/home`. And it works.

I need to create a custom controller to submit forms with an API bypassing Sitecore. So I have `FormsController` (inheriting from MVC controller) with an action named "Test" taking no parameters.

I defined the route in the initialize pipeline like this:

```
public class Initialize
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        MapRoutes();
        GlassMapperSc.Start();
    }

    private void MapRoutes()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
                "Forms.Test", 
                "forms/test", 
                new
                {
                    controller = "FormsController",
                    action = "Test"
                },
                new[] { "Forms.Controller.Namespace" });
     }
}
```

The route is added to the route table correctly, and it's there when I debug it.
Now, when I try to call method "test", the route is not found and the debugger doesn't hit the breakpoint in the action.

I'm trying different routes:

- `/localhost/mysite/home/forms/test`
- `/localhost/forms/test` (default website)

But no luck so far.

**---- UPDATE ---**

Going deeper into it, I noticed that there's something wrong with Sitecore's behavior. The `TransferRoutedRequest` processor is supposed to abort the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline, giving control back to MVC, in case the context item is null (simplifying). It happens after some checks, among which is one on RoutTable data. But the call to `RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData` returns always null, which makes the processor return without aborting the pipeline. I overrode it to make it abort the pipeline correctly, but still, even if I it calls method `args.AbortPipeline()`, pipeline is not aborted and route not resolved.

this is how the original `TransferRoutedRequest` looked like:

```
public class TransferRoutedRequest : HttpRequestProcessor
{
  public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
  {
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");
    RouteData routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData((HttpContextBase) new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
    if (routeData == null)
      return;
    RouteValueDictionary routeValueDictionary = ObjectExtensions.ValueOrDefault<Route, RouteValueDictionary>(routeData.Route as Route, (Func<Route, RouteValueDictionary>) (r => r.Defaults));
    if (routeValueDictionary != null && routeValueDictionary.ContainsKey("scIsFallThrough"))
      return;
    args.AbortPipeline();
   }
}
```

and this is how I overrode it:

```
public class TransferRoutedRequest : global::Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.HttpRequest.TransferRoutedRequest
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (Context.Item == null || Context.Item.Visualization.Layout == null)
            args.AbortPipeline();
        else
            base.Process(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got it working correctly. As I wrote `TransferRoutedRequest` wasn't working as expected, so I had to override it. Still, even if it worked as it's supposed to, the route wasn't being resolved. The problem was in the pipeline configuration. Thanks to a colleague I opened SitecoreRocks pipeline tool and it showed the pipeline was registered in a position too far away from where it should have been, so it was never hit (I had registered it after `ItemResolver`, as it was on the original configuration). I patched it before `LayoutResolver` and that did the trick. The route was resolved.
Still, Sitecore wasn't able to create an instance of the type, as it was in another assembly. Even specifying the controller's namespace didn't solve the problem. So I had to make some modifications and override CreateController method of ControllerFactory class and override InitializeControllerFactory processor (which I already had modified to be able to work with a DI container), writing a new `ControllerFactory` and a new `SitecoreControllerFactory`.

The final code looks like this:

```
public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controller = SC.Context.Item == null || SC.Context.Item.Visualization.Layout == null
                        ? base.GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName)
                        : TypeHelper.GetType(controllerName);

        return GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controller);
    }
```

In case I'm dealing with a Sitecore item, I use `TypeHelper` to return current controller type from a controller rendering or layout. Otherwise I use `DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerType` to resolve the custom route.

The only thing to be careful: in case 2 or more namespaces have a controller with the same name and action, it's mandatory to add a namespace in order to identify them.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a working example taken from one of my projects.

Custom Route Registration:

```cs
namespace Test.Project.Pipelines.Initialize
{
    public class InitRoutes : Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes
    {
        public override void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        protected virtual void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Test", // Route name
                "api/test/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                 new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Initialize Pipeline Config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
     <pipelines>
         <initialize>
            <processor type="Test.Project.Pipelines.Initialize.InitRoutes, Test.Project"
         patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
        </initialize>
     </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will create a route for you. In global.asax.cs you will call RegisterRoutes from App_Start event handler:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

And there you specify your route as:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "test",
             url: "mvc/Forms/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Forms", action = "Test", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
    }
```

You will have /mvc/ prefix in this case that will handle your route to specifies controller, so you will call it as:

```
/mvc/Forms/Test/{you_may_pass_some_optional_GUID_here}
```

This will route to FormsController class action method Test(string id) but you may omit id parameter

Comment: You are replicating my (not working) example, with the addition of a **WRONG practice**: to modify the `Application_Start` method. I have no access to the global asax, and even if I had, I wouldn't touch it. The right way of doing it is through the initialize pipeline, adding configuration to the App_Config/include folder. Or, as a second option, through decorating your own init class with `assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod`

Comment: Of course I do realize it is better to avoid modifications of global.asax.cs for at least maintenance purposes - http://sirchicken.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/leaving-globalasax-in-sitecore-untouched.html - I just simplified it for understanding. The example of a snippet is a **working** code as I have tested it in advance

Comment: Have you read what I've written? It's the same example you wrote, but it doesn't work for me. So the point is: I know how the usual tchnique works, but it's not working in my case. So what's the point of answering with the usual method? 
Moreover: did you create a new website configuration in sitecore? If yes, did you test your method from within the new created website? I don't think so...

Comment: Dear Hellraiser, @MartinMiles tries to help you and you're unkind. If I were you I would not expect that anyone else will even try to help

Comment: Dear Marek and Martin. I am sorry. I didn't mean to be rude. But I only post a message here only when I have a real problem. As I already specified, I perfectly know how this should work. But, for some unknown reason it doesn't. Moreover, the goal of StackOverflow should be not only solve problems, but to teach people how to do it the proper way. I noticed Martin wrote a wrong practice, and I let him know. 
Sometimes it's difficult to understand someone's intentions and mood here. So if I offended someone, I apologize. It wasn't my intention to do that.