# Sitecore MVC Route Set up

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, angular-ui-router, sitecore, autofac

I am trying to create Custom MVC Routes for my sitecore application.  I was looking at this link at SO[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559784/sitecore-custom-mvc-controllers-and-routes). 
While i have made the configuration - i dont understand how to link the route to my controller as my controller doesnt have the name "controller" and it is not part of Controller folder. 
I have the following set up

My "Controller class"

```
   namespace project2
{
    public class UserApi : ApiController
    {
       [HttpPost]
        public bool Login(ILogin request)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

My Routing Setup

```
  public class InitRoutes : Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes
    {
        public override void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
        protected virtual void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Accounts",
                "authapi/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
        }

    }
```

My Autofac Dependency Injection

```
   AutofacContainerFactory.ContainerBuilder.RegisterType<UserApi>().As<UserApi>().SingleInstance();
```

Finally my Pipeline :

```
<processor type="Project2.InitRoutes, Project2"
         patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
```

What i don't understand is
When i make a call from angular

> mysite.com/api/userapi/login

How will it route the call to my Userapi Class?

i  get that **controller type is null** in Autofac Controller factory
  What am i missing.

```
 public class AutofacControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
           protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext context, Type controllerType)
        {
           IController controller = (IController) DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(controllerType);
          return controller 
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that RegisterRoutes is being called, you can check that by debugging, also in your code i can't see that you are using account controller, here my answer assuming UserApi is the controller.

in Sitecore if you want to make ajax call for MVC action, , you have to do like this in register route table :

**MVC:**

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("UserApi", "UserApi/Login", new { controller = "UserApi", action = "Login" });
```

and your call will be like this :

```
mysite.com/userapi/login
```

if you want to use WebAPI, you can use the same route that you have but you may need to change "api" to something different "myapi" and your class should be derived from ApiController :

**WebAPI:**

```
public class UserApi:ApiController
{
 public bool Login(ILogin request)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

and in register route :

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                    "UserAPI",
                    "myapi/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                    );
```

and your call will be like this :

```
mysite.com/myapi/userapi/login
```

Comment: Thanks @Ayman-barhoum. I tried this. Autofac interferes and i always get Controllertype as null.  i have updated the autofact part of the code.